# Разделение программы на модули (C# winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms

Скажите пожалуйста можно ли разделить программу на модули.

Что я имею в виду. Допустим я пишу программу на WinForms. Есть главное окно интерфейс будет отображаться каждому пользователю, но на этой главной программе есть контроли, которые отвечают за переход на другие окна, и в зависимости от версии программы у них будут соответствующие контроли.

Можно ли как-то вынести реализацию каждого модуля в отдельную DLL чтобы в будущем подтягивать эти формы в зависимости от версии которую заказал клиент?

Comment: В обработчике кнопки можно тем же свитчкейсом инициализировать нужную форму в зависимости от усллвий

Comment: Можно, гуглите модули PRISM или MEF

Comment: PRISM  интересно оно только под wpf или под формы пойдет?

Comment: @Max [гуглится](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Extended-Prism-Framework-d3fc6fe6) же за 2 секунды